# Sine integral as a soliton profile?

Tags: integrable-systems, solitons

Among the most commonly known 1+1 soliton/solitary-wave profiles are:

$\tan^{-1}(\exp(x-vt))$ for Sine-Gordon,

$\tanh(x-vt)$ for $\phi^4$,

$\operatorname{sech}^2(x-vt)$ for KdV.

My question is:

Is there any known model in which the soliton profile takes the form of Sine Integral $\operatorname{Si}(x-vt)$?

EDIT:

More generally and correctly speaking, is there any soliton profile that wiggles similarly as the $Si$ function? Especially topological solitons like Sine-Gordon or $\phi^4$.

[image]

Comment: Soliton profiles goes toward their asymptotes exponentially fast. The $\operatorname{Si}$ function does not converge to $\frac\pi2$ exponentially but algebraicaly so this function is not *localized* as a soliton.

Comment: @Tom-Tom Good point. I edited the question.

Comment: @Chromatic - The solutions for bore waves look similar to this for the KdV equation.  If you add sufficient dissipation in the KdV equation, a soliton will asymptote to something similar to what you show in your plot.  The book _Linear and Nonlinear Waves_ by G.B. Whitham has good discussions about this in Chapter 13.  Sagdeev's book, _Nonlinear Physics: From the Pendulum to Turbulence and Chaos_ discusses this in depth in Chapter 8.  The solutions can involve other Jacobian elliptic functions as well, by the way...

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thanks. I have read Whitham's. I am actually working on topological solitons like $\phi^4$ or SG. KdV is a different system whose solitons are not topological. So it is not an direct answer that I am looking for, but still quite stimulating, especially how the wiggling stems from the nonlinear equation at certain limits.